# QML How to use MessageDialog in VS2022 with QT Visual Studio Tools

Tags: modal-dialog, qml

I would like to use the message dialog in a qt application, but I get the following error

```
QQmlApplicationEngine failed to load component
qrc:/display/x86/qml/display/x86/Main.qml:6:2: plugin cannot be loaded for module "QtQuick.Dialogs": Cannot protect module QtQuick.Dialogs 2 as it was never registered
```

The following components are referenced in the VS project:

[image]

I included the MessageBox in the QML page using the following code

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15
import QtQuick.Dialogs 2.15


MessageDialog {
    id: dialog
    text: "The document has been modified."
    informativeText: "Do you want to save your changes?"
    buttons: MessageDialog.Ok | MessageDialog.Cancel
    onAccepted: document.save()
    onCancel: dialog.close()
}
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-dialogs-messagedialog.html) for Qt 5.15 says to use `import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.3`. If you use [Qt 6](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-dialogs-messagedialog.html) avoid using the version in the import statement, just use `import QtQuick.Dialogs`.

Comment: Thanks for soon response, solves the problem